# How to split the long headings of a table in multiple lines using latex?

Tags: latex, tabular, multirow

How to create a table using latex exactly as follows. The table has to fit 1 column in the 2 column page format but the table headings are too long and the content in the first column also too long. So, I want to split the column headings and content of the first column in multiple lines with the bold format.

[image: table]

Not too sure why \makecell is not co-operating for bold the text and design a solid border  all over but here's my latex code:

```
\begin{table}[h]    
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|L|L|L|L|L|}
\toprule

\makecell[lt]{Type} 
&\makecell[lt]{Financial \\ benefit \\ of the \\users}
& \makecell[lt]{Financial\\ loss of the \\ users} 
&\makecell[lt]{Interruption \\ of user’ \\ daily activity}
&\makecell[lt]{Monetary \\ reward \\ for works}\\

\midrule
\makecell[lt]{Category 1: \\ Work in \\ the retail \\ sector}
 & \ding{51}
 & \ding{51}
 & 
 & \ding{51}\\
 
\midrule
\makecell[lt]{Category 2: \\ Work in \\ the industry \\ sector}
 & \ding{51}
 & \ding{51}
 & \ding{51}
 & \ding{51}\\
 
\midrule
\makecell[lt]{Category 3: \\ Work in \\ the corporate \\ sector}
 & \ding{51}
 & \ding{51}
 & \ding{51}
 & \ding{51}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `package` `array` provides you a new tabular cell type

```
p={fixed width}
```

whit this cell type, you can define two new cell types that meets your alignemt requirements:

```
\newcolumntype{F}[1]{%
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{%
    >{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%
```

[image: output]

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{F}[1]{%
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{%
    >{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|F{0.2\textwidth}|T{0.2\textwidth}|T{0.2\textwidth}|T{0.2\textwidth}|T{0.2\textwidth}|}
\hline
\textbf{\hfil Type}&
\textbf{Financial benefit of the users}&
\textbf{Financial loss of the users }&
\textbf{Interruption of user daily activity}&
\textbf{Monetary reward for works}\\ 
\hline
\textbf{Category 1: Work in  the retail  sector } &\textbf{v}&&v&v \\
\hline
\textbf{Category 2: Work in  the industry  sector} &v&v&v&v \\  
\hline
\textbf{Category 3: Work in  the corporate  sector}  &&v&v&v \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```